# Ubuntu 18.04LTS - won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04

After install ubuntu 18.04LTS using USB. In the boot menu, I choose Ubuntu but I get an error, see picture.

What should I do to fix it and boot Ubuntu?

[[image: Windows boot menu[1]]

Comment: Does Windows boot?  Also, have you followed the on-screen advice?

Comment: What boot menu are choosing from? Did you install GRUB with Ubuntu 18.04 or are you using the Windows bootloader?

Comment: I boot ubuntu 18.04 while i am using windows 10 education. After boot ubuntu, i use easyBCD to setup menuboot. that 's my process

Comment: when start my laptop, on menuboot, i choose ubuntu 18.04LTS which i already setup by using easyBCD and this error appear.